# How do I remove nan from a list in all columns and convert some columns containing list to string and int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: DataFrame Image]

As you can see from the picture, some column has a list of values containing nan, I want to remove those and leave with the values, then convert it to `string` or `int` depending on the column.
For the specific row of column that look like [nan, nan] or more nan's in a list, I want to replace it with only nan.

**For example:**

```
[149-1213(R.2), nan] -> 149-1213(R.2)

[23500, nan] -> 23500

[nan, nan, nan] -> nan

[6000] -> 6000

[2015-03-08 00:00:00, nan, nan] -> 2015-03-08 00:00:00

[nan, SERVICE CHARGE] -> SERVICE CHARGE
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: In fact you need to take the first element of the list?

Comment: What if there are two or more non-NaN elements in the list?

Comment: @Corralien in some list, the nan value come first like [nan, something, nan, something]

Comment: Did you create the `NaNs` yourself? You might wanna correct it at the source.

Comment: well if it were for the NAN's only your can always use the dataframe with fillna function and it will fill it with the desired values.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html